# Can I control the volume when my AirPods are connected to a non-Apple mp3 player?

Tags: bluetooth, airpods

I have a Sony Walkman MP3 player, and have been given some AirPods (gen 1 or 2 as far as I can see, not Pro). These connect fine to the Walkman via Bluetooth, but I don't seem to be able to control the volume. Using the volume controls on the Walkman doesn't do anything, and I can't find any indication that I can do this by tapping the AirPods.

All I have found online is that double-tapping either pod skips forward one track. Can't see to skip back, can't pause/resume and can't change volume.

Anyone able to advise? Is any of this possible?

Comment: Not sure they are compatible. Also, have you paired them properly? How have you proceeded?

Comment: I use a Sony Walkman NW-A55.   You’re not going to get much functionality with the AirPods.  Before I ditched my AirPods, I was able to connect, but most features and functions were unavailable.  Like you said, the volume *should* increase if you increase it on the Walkman, but it doesn’t on the AirPod.  I switched to Sennheisers and everything works as it should.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for the reply. As it happens, I've got the NWZ-A15, but I guess it's the same. I understand I'm not going to get all the functionality with a non-Apple device, but I expected a bit more than only being able to skip forwards! Which Sennheisers model did you get? Thanks again

Comment: I got the True Wireless 2 Earbuds.  The noise cancelling on these are amazing for calls and I find the (music) audio very rich.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for that!

Comment: New AirPods Pro's support swipe gestures for volume, if you wanna try that. You could try long pressing for voice commands if the device supports it and allows increasing the volume that way.

Comment: @JBallin Thanks, but I don't have the Pros, just the regular ones.